# JQuery Ajax and WCF Keeping session alive

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I am calling a WCF Webservice via JQuery Ajax method. The method in my WCF service doesn't access the session in anyway but it seems to be keeping my site session active thus not timing out after 3 minutes which i have set in my Web.Config. Any help would be appreciated as I'm quite new to WCF.

Comment: I'm not after accessing the session, im just after returning data from the database and its doing that successfully but for some reason since i have put the Ajax call in my site is no longer timing out the session

Comment: I have moved the WCF Service to a separate service project this has fixed the issue with the session timeout. I did notice when i was calling the service in the same project as my aspx page it was passing the cookie (session id) with the http request.